# MFC DLL calls AfxWinInit and crashes application

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have an MFC .exe application, and I created another project for a DLL with MFC dynamically linked to it.

Now, when I import that DLL through LoadLibrary, it crashes my application, because when the importing is done, the DLL calls `AfxWinInit()`.

Should the DLL call `AfxWinInit()`? How do I avoid it? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: If it is already a MFC application, you don't need to call in in that DLL

Comment: @Matt I did not create any code calling it myself, It is called inside internal MFC/windows API code

Answer (score 3):

In your MFC application `WinMain()` calls `AfxWinMain().` The `AfxWinInit()` is called at the beginning of `AfxWinMain().` So the initialization is done by framework for you. There is no need to initialize it again.

MFC DLLs provide their own entry point, so you're not supposed to write one yourself. If you plan to write a DLL with MFC support, I'd suggest you start with a fresh MFC DLL created by the app wizard and then move your code there.

For MFC applications that load extension DLLs, use `AfxLoadLibrary` instead of `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: I did not create any code myself. In fact, the app wizard created a CWinApp class instance for me, which also crashed the application when it called its constructor. I removed the instance (called `theApp`) and now the DLL crashes at `AfxWinInit`

Comment: You should create **MFC Extension** library type.

Comment: When I create an MFC extension lib, I get errors like `error C2504: 'CMFCPropertyGridCtrl' : base class undefined error C2653: 'CMFCPropertyGridCtrl' : is not a class or namespace name